# get values from BsonArray in scala

Tags: scala, mongo-scala-driver

I'm interesting how can I transfor value from BsonArray to Seq[String] with mongodb scala driver.
I'm getting

```
value = Document((_id,BsonObjectId{value=5b112ca63b4dbed418a55eff}), (name,BsonString{value='test'}), (type,BsonString{value='test'}), (tags,BsonArray{values=[BsonString{value='test'}]}))
```

from mongodb.
I want to get tags as Seq[String]:

```
 value.get[BsonArray](TagsKey).get.getValues.stream.map(tag => tag.asString().getValue).collect[List[String],AnyRef](Collectors.toList)
```

but getting compiller error

> Too many types arguments for collect

```
value.get[BsonArray](TagsKey).get.getValues.stream.map(tag => tag.asString().getValue).collect(Collectors.toList)
```

Is not working too.

I don't understand why. May be there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Done with:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
value.get[BsonArray](TagsKey).get.getValues.asScala.map(tag => tag.asString().getValue)
```